# Banner Previsão do Tempo não carrega com HTTPS

Tags: http-status

Quando coloco o código do banner previsão do tempo do site (http://www.tempoagora.com.br) em meu site que possui o protocolo HTTPS. O banner não carrega.

O código que o site gera é este:

E mesmo mudando o link "http://www.tempoagora.com.br/ta-widgets?cidades=Araguari-MG&tipo=vertical" para "//www.tempoagora.com.br/ta-widgets?cidades=Araguari-MG&tipo=vertical", retirando o protocolo o banner não carrega.

Alguém tem alguma solução para resolver este problema?

Comment: Como o estás a integrar no teu site? via `<iframe>`?

Comment: sim sim. coloquei o codigo conforme o site gera: <iframe frameborder="0" allowtransparency="yes" scrolling="no" width="150" height="260" src="http://www.tempoagora.com.br/ta-widgets?cidades=Araguari-MG&amp;tipo=vertical"></iframe>

Comment: Já passei por isso. O navegador bloqueia porque considera não seguro. A única solução que encontrei na época foi consultar a previsão via cURL no XML que o site disponibilizava

Comment: Isso mesmo Lucas. O Console me mostra a Seguinte mensagem de erro: This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS. Poderia me ajudar  com este problema? Tem algum exemplo de cURL no XML? Não tenho conhecimento nisso.

Comment: Sabe se a cURL funciona com aspx?